# Avoid inserting the same account number (RIB) for two providers pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I work with Oracle EBS r12, I have the table : AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL with the below structure:

vendor_site_id (id), vendor_id not null, attribute4 varchar(150)

i want to create a trigger pl/sql that check if the attribute4 exists in the table or not, if exists so the update or insert are denied in this table, if the fields don't exists so you can update or insert the new record.

Please help us.

best regards,

Comment: What you want to implement is already available, it is called a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update, but the unique id is vendor_site_id, attribute4 is not null actually, and i can't used like unique, because i have a recird in this table when the attribute4 is null, so i need to developp trigger and i don't like change in table structure.

Comment: @KaushikNayak, you feedback please

Comment: Your comment is somewhat confusing. Why can't you use a constraint? Oracle allows multiple unique constraints on a single table. In addition, if you have a nullable column (attribute4), your new unique constraint will only apply to rows with values, because of the nature of how Oracle treats nulls--they are not indexed.